# BFG Repo Cleaner for items re-introduced to history after a previous successful purge

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

If an item was removed by BFG cleaner from history, then someone didn't purge their old clone, but instead just deleted the file and then later pushed, will BFG Cleaner still be able to purge that same file again if I use just the filename?  Or do I need to do some repo shenannigans to get HEAD back to the offending point in history?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that yes, this is exactly what it does. I decided to just try it, using a file name mined from the history which did not exist in the HEAD and it worked great. The default expectation on BFG in fact is that you will first delete what you need to remove from your local and then run BFG to get rid of it, since it defaults to not affecting HEAD anyway.